# Apache Isis build failure migrating from v1.12.2. Unknown repositories ApplicationUser,

Tags: isis

I am migrating an Apache Isis application from version 1.12.2 and currently using the legacy addons Security, Audit, and SessionLogger. I plan on updating to the latest Isis version and using the latest Incode addons here.

When changing the Isis version to 1.13.0  it fails the build. I did not see anything in the migration notes that will fix this. The build error is unkown repository for ApplicationRole, ApplicationTenancy, ApplicationUser. The bootstrap class lists the addon modules and there are no errors using Isis 1.12.2.

(update)

I thought it possible that Isis and the Incode addons should upgrade together at some point and someone would mention it, but I wasn't sure. Then looking more into this, I noticed the Apache Isis *isis-app-todoapp* uses an Isis version one major release higher, as well as the Incode addons, which are also one major release higher than what I have. Any idea about this? I would like to get to the latest Isis and Incode versions.

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] @DomainObject annotation on org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.role.ApplicationRole specifies unknown  repository 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.role.ApplicationRoleRepository'
[ERROR] @DomainObject annotation on org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.tenancy.ApplicationTenancy specifies unknown repository 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.tenancy.ApplicationTenancyRepository'
[ERROR] @DomainObject annotation on org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.user.ApplicationUser specifies unknown repository 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.user.ApplicationUserRepository'
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[INFO] calling @PreDestroy on all domain services
[INFO] shutting down 
org.apache.isis.core.metamodel.specloader.SpecificationLoader@1e2fe282
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] App ................................. SUCCESS [  0.652s]
[INFO] App  DOM ............................. FAILURE [ 37.945s]
[INFO] App  Fixtures ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] App  App ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] App  Webapp .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.974 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-25T09:47:05-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 84M/692M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.isis.tool:isis-maven-plugin:1.13.2:validate (default) on project App-dom: 3 meta-model problems found. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: I was able to build when removing a build profile when !skip.isis-validate.
`
<activation>
    <property>
     <name>!skip.isis-validate</name>
    </property>
   </activation>
`
and the dependency on com.google.guava that has a comment: 'workaround to avoid conflict with plexus-default'. It doesn't run though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing a maven build-profile slash validation step, after reading similar SO question, and updating the Incode addon modules with each major Isis release. I successfully went through Apache Isis release 1.13.0, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.2.

Comment: I had to revert the changes my custom rest endpoints won't return.